# Unable to get the current downloading file size using Android Download Manager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I call the service below to handle the download of a given URL. As you can see in the snippet below I want to assign the current downloading file size to `total_size`.

However (using the Eclipse debugger) its value remains -1 even though the file is getting properly downloaded. Suggestions?

```
public class DownloadManagerService extends IntentService {

    public final static String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_STARTED= "com.youzik.app.intent.action.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_STARTED";
    public static final String DATA = "download";
    public static final String URL = "url";

    public DownloadManagerService() {
        super("DownloadManagerService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent service) {
        Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(service.getStringExtra(URL)));
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        long downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));

        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.v("DownloadManagerService", "download list is empty");
            return;
        }

        Download dl = new Download();
        dl.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));
        dl.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE)));
        dl.setUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)));

        int total_size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks okay. Maybe the server you want to download from does not support this.

Comment: I tested it. It's ok. Pleases get the total file size after  > 1s. I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
q.setFilterById(extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID));
Cursor c = YOUR_DM.query(q);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
        // process download
        title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
        // get other required data by changing the constant passed to getColumnIndex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given required user-permission in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also , give run time permission on android marshmallow and above version.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        //do your check here
        askForPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXST);
        askForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXST);
    }


  private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), permission)) {

            //This is called if user has denied the permission before
            //In this case I am just asking the permission again
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Permission :: ","is already granted");
    }
}


 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        switch (requestCode) {
            //Location
            case 1:
                // askForGPS();
                break;
            //Call
            case 2:

                break;
            //Write external Storage
            case 3:
                Log.d("Permission :: ","Write external Storage");
                break;
            //Read External Storage
            case 4:
             /*   Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 11);*/
                Log.d("Permission :: ","Read External Storage");
                break;
            //Camera
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```